# dh: unable to load addon autoreconf in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mininet, openvswitch

I am working with Openvswitch to create mpls vpn network on mininet platform. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 server with kernel version: **4.4.0**-97-generic. I am trying to upgrade my openvswitch from 2.0.0 version to version **2.5.2** which is supported by kernel version **4.4.0** . I am following the steps for openvswitch upgrade guide given on [Openvswitch upgrade guide](https://techandtrains.com/2013/10/24/another-way-to-upgrade-open-vswitch-in-mininet/)

When I try to build the debian packages I get the following error:

---

```
ash@ash:~/openvswitch/openvswitch-2.5.2$ DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS='parallel=2 nocheck' fakeroot debian/rules binary
dh binary --with autoreconf,python2 --parallel
dh: unable to load addon autoreconf: Can't locate 
Debian/Debhelper/Sequence/autoreconf.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Debian::Debhelper::Sequence::autoreconf module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at (eval 13) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 13) line 2.
debian/rules:25: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** ***[binary] Error 2***
```

I am not exactly getting what is causing this problem? 
I am new to linux system and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install dh-autoreconf package as:

```
# apt install dh-autoreconf
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It solved my problem, too. I'm curious where you learned about the related knowledge (such as the documentation source). I'm also kind of new to Linux and always impressed by how much other people know about this system.

Comment: It's nothing special or hard. The error message said: "_autoreconf: Can't locate_" and searched for ..`Sequence/autoreconf.pm`. Then I did a quick search for this file: `apt-file search Sequence/autoreconf.pm` and the answer is only one package: `dh-autoreconf`. It's easy, just read the error message.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `apt-file`! I actually read the error message but had no idea of using `apt-file` to find the missing file. I tried it just now and it showed me the package, too. Amazing!